# MDX Query to return the number of records

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2012

Below is my MDX query

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
       { [Measures].[Fact Sample Count] } ON COLUMNS,
        NON EMPTY 
        { (
        [Fact Sample].[Sample Reference No].[Sample Reference No].ALLMEMBERS 
        ) } ON ROWS 
 FROM [LIMSInstCube] 
      WHERE ( [Dim Material Master].[Material Master ID].&[999] )
```

So it gives 10 records as my out put. I have a requirement where I have to show the number of records that are returned from the query i.e 10. Can any one please help me how to get the records count.

Comment: Hello Please , Can any one help me with the syntax of getting number of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the count:

```
NonEmpty
(
{[Fact Sample].[Sample Reference No].[Sample Reference No].ALLMEMBERS},
([Dim Material Master].[Material Master ID].&[999], [Measures].[Fact Sample Count])
).Count
```

The idea is to get the set of non-empty members from the `[Fact Sample].[Sample Reference No].[Sample Reference No]` level for the `material master ID` 999 which have a non-zero(non-null) `fact sample count`.

**EDIT** : What I created for you is a measure. You have to declare a calculated member(measure) and write the definition there and then access it using the regular `SELECT {...} FROM {...} WHERE {...}` construct.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.YourCustomizedCountMeasure AS
NonEmpty (
          [Fact Sample].[Sample Reference No].[Sample Reference No].ALLMEMBERS, 
          ([Dim Material Master].[Material Master ID].&[999], [Measures].[Fact Sample Count])
         ).Count

SELECT  Measures.YourCustomizedCountMeasure ON 0
FROM [LIMSInstCube]
```

Comment: hello Sourav, Sorry may be i am asking a dumb question but where should i put the query i mean on rows or on columns i can you please elaborate?

Comment: i tried doing below                                                                             SELECT NON EMPTY 
       { [Measures].[Fact Sample Count] } ON COLUMNS,
        NonEmpty
(
{[Fact Sample].[Sample Reference No].[Sample Reference No].ALLMEMBERS},
([Dim Material Master].[Material Master ID].&[999], [Measures].[Fact Sample Count])
).CountON )ROWS 
 FROM [LIMSInstCube] 
      WHERE ( [Dim Material Master].[Material Master ID].&[999] )

Comment: thanks a lot it did the magic i am new person to MDX can you suggest some good basic stuff for MDX . And once again thank you

Comment: Google for "MDX function reference" and just try out all the functions one by one. You will get stuck in some places and then you can google for the error. Then you would be redirected to online blogs or stackoverflow. That is how I am learning. Else, google for Chris Webb's or Mosha's blogs. They are among the sharpest MDX experts around. You can also get a lot of good books on MDX. All the best.