# MDX Record Count

Tags: mdx

Can any one tell me how to get the record count that is a result of a MDX query?I have tried various methods and I haven't really got a solution for that.I am a beginner in MDX queries.

Comment: If you are pulling the results into SSRS then maybe best to count the records in SSRS. The concept of a sub-query, similar to t-sql, doesn't really exist in MDX. Also though you could create a new measure in your cube that is a count of whatever it is you need to count

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737975/mdx-query-to-return-the-number-of-records on which I have added a solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[amount] as 
        COUNT(
            [your_dimension].[your_dimension_property].Members
        ) 
SELECT {[Measures].[amount]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [your_awesome_cube]
```

A code like this will return to you the amount of members in your dimension, the `COUNT` method have this syntax 
`Count(Set_Expression [ , ( EXCLUDEEMPTY | INCLUDEEMPTY ) ] )`
so you can do a lot of things, like filter your search

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure in the cube that is a count or distinct count.

Answer (score 0):

1) open the cube

2) Right click on the fact table on which that measure sits

3) Select `New Measure...`

4) Dropdown the list and select the aggregation

5) In the source column section, select the column you want the aggregation on (if u cant find it, click on `show all columns` on the bottom- this depends on what you are aggregating)

Answer (score 0):

with member 
Measures.Counts as
[your_dimension].[your_dimension_property].Children.COUNT

select Measures.Counts on 0
FROM [your_awesome_cube]

Answer (score 0):

When you say record count, you basicly are saying the valid combinations of your row axis.

Lets take a basic example, the query returns 3637 rows, of which 1 row is parctically the column name row.

```
select [Measures].[Sales Amount] on columns, 
(
[Customer].[Country].[Country],
[Product].[Product].[Product]
) on rows
from [Adventure Works]
```

Now to get the row count without running the query, lets put the combinations in count function and put the count function in a runtime measure

This Returns 3636 row.
    with member [Measures].[rowCount]
    as 
    count(([Customer].[Country].[Country],[Product].[Product].[Product]))
    select [Measures].[rowCount] on columns from [Adventure Works]

Notice I have not eleminated the null combinations on rows. Lets do that next

The query returns 2101 rows , again one row from column headers.
    select [Measures].[Sales Amount] on columns, 
    non empty 
    (
    [Customer].[Country].[Country],
    [Product].[Product].[Product]
    ) on rows
    from [Adventure Works]

Now lets count the rows

This returns 2100 rows.
    with member [Measures].[rowCount]
    as 
    count(nonempty(( [Customer].[Country].[Country],[Product].[Product].[Product])
    ,{[Measures].[Sales Amount]}
    ))
    select [Measures].[rowCount] 
    on columns from [Adventure Works]

Till now we had measure from just one measure group, now lets try with multiple measure groups.

```
select {[Measures].[Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} on columns, 
non empty 
(
[Customer].[Country].[Country],
[Product].[Product].[Product]
) on rows
from [Adventure Works]
//Cell set consists of 2101 rows and 3 columns.

//Wrong way
with member [Measures].[rowCount]
as 
count(nonempty(( [Customer].[Country].[Country],[Product].[Product].[Product])
,{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
))
select [Measures].[rowCount] on columns from [Adventure Works]
//935

//Right way
with member [Measures].[rowCount]
as 
count(nonempty(( [Customer].[Country].[Country],[Product].[Product].[Product])
,{[Measures].[Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
))
select [Measures].[rowCount] 
on columns from [Adventure Works]
///2100
```

Notice when we use just a single measure the result may not be correct . If the measure we use has a null value then the combination would be removed. Where as in our rows the other measure will ensure that the combination appears.

Now Lets add a filter to the picture.

```
select {[Measures].[Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} on columns, 
non empty
filter( 
(
[Customer].[Country].[Country],
[Product].[Product].[Product]
)
,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>5000) on rows
from [Adventure Works]
//Cell set consists of 586 rows and 3 columns.

//Wrong way
with member [Measures].[rowCount]
as 
count(nonempty(( [Customer].[Country].[Country],[Product].[Product].[Product])
,{[Measures].[Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
))
select [Measures].[rowCount] 
on columns from [Adventure Works]
//2100

//Right way
with member [Measures].[rowCount]
as 
count(nonempty(
filter(([Customer].[Country].[Country],[Product].[Product].[Product]),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>5000) 
,{[Measures].[Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
))
select [Measures].[rowCount] 
on columns from [Adventure Works]
///585
```

Again till i gave the RowCount measure the exact senario that I have on my row axis it fails.