# MDX of records returned

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm building **SSRS** report. In **Query Designer** I have a report query. I need to count **total records returned** by this query.

[image]

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737975/mdx-query-to-return-the-number-of-records?rq=1

Comment: Can you please provide your query as an example?

Comment: Why don't you use the [COUNTROWS()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255215(v=sql.110).aspx) function?.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use MDX for counting rows and show the result in the report but that would imply the creation of an additional dataset. The easiest way if you need to show the count of rows is using `COUNTROWS()` function.

In a SSRS textbox, tablix or expression you need to get the total of rows of an specific dataset use:

```
=COUNTROWS("DataSetName")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of the dataset you created using Query Designer.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: (upped) I like this approach - getting a row count within pure mdx is a nightmare so much better to do in the client